# Next and Previous Arrow Buttons to Navigate through Web URLs With JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, navigation, redirect

I am very new to JavaScript so please bear with me. 
I am trying to create a next and previous arrow navigation that will cycle through a group of web pages but I am missing a key piece of code that keeps track of which web page I am on so it can determine the sequence. Any help is most appreciated!

This is the script I have written so far:

```
"use strict";
var myPage = [];
myPage[0] = "apples";
myPage[1] = "oranges";
myPage[2] = "bananas";
myPage[3] = "kiwi";

var myPageSrc = "file:///D:site/fruit/";

var myPageEnd = ".html";

var i = 0;

function loadPage(){
  window.location.assign(myPageSrc + myPage[i] + myPageEnd);
}

function prev(){
  if (i <= 0) {
    i = myPage.length;
    loadPage();
  } else {
    i = i - 1;
    loadPage();
  }
}

function next(){
  i = i + 1;
  if (i >= myPage.length) {
    i = 0;
    loadPage();
  } else {
    loadPage();
  }
}
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<div class = "col-md-2"> 
<a href="" class="nav-prev floatleft" original-title="Previous" onClick="prev();return   false;"> <img src="../img/left.png"> </a>
<a href="" class="nav-prev floatright" original-title="Next" onClick="next();return false;"> <img src="../img/next.png"> </a>
</div>
<script src="../js/nextprevnav.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you trying to do this with JavaScript? Instead of straight up html?

Comment: Honestly, because I am not sure how to do it with HTML and thought one JavaScript would work since I have about 50 or so web pages that I want to cycle through. Would HTML be best? Do you mean I should just enter in each next/previous href for each web page?

Comment: If you have 50 static HTML pages then I would just make the links manually. If you wanted to make dynamic links on each page for page numbers like "apples1.html", "apples2.html" I would use PHP for that instead of JavaScript. But that's a completely separate issue...

Comment: Thanks! Good point! Would work too if someone has JavaScript turned off.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's possible to do this with HTML?

There would be 2 options: use an iFrame, or set a Cookie.

Once you have left the page, you have also lost all your variables. You would use a cookie to track data once the user has left and returned. Since you said you are learning Javascript, I would recommend using an iFrame. Set an iframe in the webpage:

```
<iframe src="http://www.google-or-something.com" id="frame" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

Then where you have your window.location.assign function, replace it with something like this:

```
document.getElementById('frame').src = myPageSrc + myPage[i] + myPageEnd;
```

Hope this helps you on your way!

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your variable `i` to this:

```
var i = myPage.indexOf(window.location.href.match(/.*\/([\.]+)\..*/)[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't code that from scratch. You could use jQuery mobile with a pagination plugin. If you don't like the jQuery mobile styling you could also use only the framework for pagination and do the styling on your own.

Please find a demo below and at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wzgODkd7GPXKe06Y5jxc?p=preview).

It's working pretty well just the position of the pagination arrows could be improved.

Also the html5 history is working with jQuery mobile and that's not in your code yet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/filamentgroup/jqm-pagination/master/jquery.mobile.pagination.css"/>
    
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/filamentgroup/jqm-pagination/master/jquery.mobile.pagination.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
      <div data-role="header"><h1>Main page</h1></div>
      <div data-role="content" class="fullHeight">
        <p>Main page content...</p>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/" />
        <ul data-role="pagination">
        <!--<li class="ui-pagination-prev"><a href="3.html">Prev</a></li>-->
        <li class="ui-pagination-next"><a href="#page1">Next</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div data-role="footer"><p>Footer &copy; 2014</p></div>
    </div>
    
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
      <div data-role="header"><h1>Page 1</h1></div>
      <div data-role="content" class="fullHeight">
      <p>Page 1 content</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p>
        
        <ul data-role="pagination">
        <li class="ui-pagination-prev"><a href="#index">Prev</a></li>
        <li class="ui-pagination-next"><a href="#page2">Next</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
      <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"><p>Footer &copy; 2014</p></div>
      
    </div>
    
     <div data-role="page" id="page2">
      <div data-role="header"><h1>Page 2</h1></div>
      <div data-role="content" class="fullHeight">
      <p>Page 2 content</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p>

        <ul data-role="pagination">
        <li class="ui-pagination-prev"><a href="#page1">Prev</a></li>
        <li class="ui-pagination-next"><a href="#page3">Next</a></li>
      </ul>
        
      </div>
      <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"><p>Footer &copy; 2014</p></div>
      
    </div>
    
    <div data-role="page" id="page3">
      <div data-role="header"><h1>Page 3</h1></div>
      <div data-role="content" class="fullHeight">
      <p>Page3 content</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p>

        <ul data-role="pagination">
        <li class="ui-pagination-prev"><a href="#page2">Prev</a></li>
        <li class="ui-pagination-next"><a href="#page1">Next</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
      <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"><p>Footer &copy; 2014</p></div>
      
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var current = 1;
        function moveImage(direction) {
            //alert(direction);
            if (direction == "left") {
                current--;
                if (current == 0)
                    current = 26;
                //alert(current);
            loadImage( current );
        } else {
                current++;
                if (current > 26)
                    current = 1;
                //alert(current);
            loadImage(current);
           }  
        }

        function loadImage( id ) {
         var image = document.getElementById("1");
         image.setAttribute('src', 'images/' + id + '.jpg');
         current = id;
         //alert(id + '.jpg');
        }
    </script>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="fotoblock" align="center">
            <img src="images/1.jpg" id="1" style="width:850px; height:423px" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav-icons" style="text-align:center">
            <a href="#" class="prev_image" title="Previous Image" onclick="moveImage('left')" style="text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold"><<</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="#" class="next_image" title="Next Image" onclick="moveImage('right')" style="text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold">>></a></div>
    </form>
```